# Phonegap interop capability

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

With Phonegap, I read you can access native OS methods. What about the other way round ? Can native app that wraps the js module call javascript methods inside that module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

totally possible here's an example -

```
NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString 
                                 stringWithFormat:@"someJSFunction();"]; 
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

I've got a blog post about the localNotifications plugin, it goes into detail about having the native iOS make callbacks to your JS

http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=117

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish apple would have better documented.

Comment: Isn't LocalNotification slow : as far as I understand there is a delay. I would need an immediate callback.

Comment: depends on how you develop it. The way I've used it it's pretty fast, no delay. Once the apps is opened the functions are called and my app reacts. You'll have to play around with using the jsCallBack and test. The example in that blog post should allow you to test.

Answer (score 0):

But of course, it would be pretty useless otherwise.